# Updating from 8.10 intrepid

Tags: upgrade, 8.10

Hello everybody ~ I am fresh off the newbie tree and waving good bye to Windows through the rear view mirror.

I just started up an old machine that has a fresh install of 8.10 on it and has never been used since.

As far as I can tell there is no gui desktop on it.  I would like to update it to the latest, 14.x?

How do I update?  Do I just over write the 8.10 with the latest?  do I wipe the 8.10 first then install? 
Can anyone please advise on this? 
Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! The best advice I can give is do not upgrade, rather install a fresh version. The reason being is you would not be upgrading just one time, but multiple times, and would probably have a lot of "loose" files left behind after each upgrade. You would be upgrading to 10,12,then 14, and since it is not an LTS (Long Term Support) it would be harder, as well as take many hours versus just a few (at most).

Comment: @NoTime  thanks for the response. I downloaded v14 disc image and burned to DVD.  I am just now trying to figure out how to switch my machine over to boot from disc. I will Google this and go from there but if you have any more comments I would love to hear them.  Thanks again for responding.

Comment: [DVD Install](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows)  is the official documentation (for DVD from Windows), [USB Install](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) (for USB stick). [Original page to check out](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/) (Look towards bottom for different OS instructions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very best way to do it is to download Ubuntu from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).

Then burn the image to disk or usb drive and set your computer to boot from that device and run Ubuntu in the try mode to see if you can run Ubuntu on that old of a computer, you may also want to try [Lubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu) it is very light on resources.

It is best to reformat the drive and start fresh, you do not want to try to upgrade.

Comment: Wild Man, thanks for the response. I downloaded v14 disc image and burned to DVD. I am just now trying to figure out how to switch my machine over to boot from disc. I will Google this and go from there but if you have any more comments I would love to hear them. Thanks again for responding.